# How to randomize only 1 variable in a class?

Tags: system-verilog

I have the following class

```
class ABC;


    rand bit[2 : 0] mode; 
    randc bit[2 : 0] mode_cylic;
    constraint range{

        mode >= 2;
        mode < 6;

    };

    constraint range_cylic{

        mode_cylic >= 2;
        mode_cylic < 6;

    };



endclass
```

I have a test object of the test class `ABC`, and I want to randomize only the `mode` variable in that object.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to disable randomization for the variable you don't want to randomize:

```
class ABC;
    rand bit[2 : 0] mode; 
    randc bit[2 : 0] mode_cylic;

    constraint range{
        mode >= 2;
        mode < 6;
    }

    constraint range_cylic{
        mode_cylic >= 2;
        mode_cylic < 6;
    }
endclass

module tb;
    ABC abc = new();
    bit result;
    initial begin
        abc.range_cylic.constraint_mode(0);
        abc.mode_cylic.rand_mode(0);
        repeat (10) begin
            result = abc.randomize();
            $display("mode=%0d mode_cylic=%0d", abc.mode, abc.mode_cylic);
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 18.8 *Disabling random variables with rand_mode()*.

This is the output I get:

```
mode=2 mode_cylic=0
mode=2 mode_cylic=0
mode=2 mode_cylic=0
mode=4 mode_cylic=0
mode=4 mode_cylic=0
mode=2 mode_cylic=0
mode=4 mode_cylic=0
mode=3 mode_cylic=0
mode=5 mode_cylic=0
mode=4 mode_cylic=0
```

---

Or, if you want `mode_cylic` to have a specific value within the `range_cylic` range, use `with`:

```
initial begin
    repeat (10) begin
        result = abc.randomize() with { mode_cylic == 5; };
        $display("mode=%0d mode_cylic=%0d", abc.mode, abc.mode_cylic);
    end
end
```

This is the output I get:

```
mode=2 mode_cylic=5
mode=2 mode_cylic=5
mode=2 mode_cylic=5
mode=4 mode_cylic=5
mode=4 mode_cylic=5
mode=2 mode_cylic=5
mode=4 mode_cylic=5
mode=3 mode_cylic=5
mode=5 mode_cylic=5
mode=4 mode_cylic=5
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to be careful when randomizing a class and only randomizing certain variables because the constraints are deactivated separately from the variables. All active constraints must succeed for a class randomization.

The simplest thing to do when you only have one or a few variables out of a larger set of random variables to randomize is using the built-in `std::randomize` method. This randomizes the variables in its arguments regardless of whether they are class variables, and does not use any class constraints.

```
std::randomize(obj.mode);
```

Any constraints you want to use must be added using a `with {expressions}` constraint.

Another thing you can do is using the class randomize method, also putting just variables you want randomized.

```
obj.randomize(mode);
```

However all class constraint must still succeed, so `mode_cylic` must already have a value 2-5, or you need to turn off the constraint using

```
obj.range_cylic.constraint_mode(0);
```

You can do a similar thing using `rand_mode()` to turn off the random variables you don't want randomized.

I would use the `rand/constraint_mode()` for turning off one variable or constraint, rather than trying turn off everything except one. It becomes very difficult to maintain as you start adding more variables/constraints to your testbench.

Try to use `std:randomize` or even better, separate your classes in to objects to be randomized separately.

Comment: Great answer, is there a way to use std::randomize() with constraints defined inside a class or even when i try to extern it outside of the class is that feasible ?

Comment: If the one variable you want to randomize is a class variable, then the constraints associated with that class object will be considered. It might help to go back and edit your question and explain what the situation is where you only want to randomize one variable. There might be an alternative approach. See the https://xyproblem.info/