# How to randomize 1 of 100 variables

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Let's say we have a class with a bunch of random variables (around 100 `rand` variables). Now, I want to randomize only one of the variables from that class and the rest of the variables should be the same. How do I do that?

```
class rand_var extends vmm_data;
    rand bit abc;
    rand bit [3:0] cde;
    rand bit en;
    ...
endclass
```

Now from one of the task, I want to randomize `abc` only, not any other variables of `rand_var`.

```
task custom_task();
    rand_var rand1;
    rand1 = new config

    if (config.randomize () with {

    }) 
    else $display("randomization failed");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way of randomizing a single variable is using the `std::randomize` instead of the `randomize` method of the class.

```
task custom_task();
    rand_var config;
    config = new();

    if (std::randomize(config.abc) with {
    /* constraints on config.abc */
    }) 
    else $display("randomization failed");
```

You can also use what's called *in-line randomization control* when calling the class `randomize` method as in

```
if (!config.randomize(abc)) $display("randomization failed");
```

But you have to be careful when doing it this way because all of the active class constraints in the `config` object must still be satisfied, even on variables not being randomized.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. What if I want to randomize two variables out of many, if there a way to do that?

Comment: You can add all the variables as a list in the argument to `randomize`.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to call `randomize` and pass only the variable you want to be random.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 18.11 *In-line random variable control*.  Here is a complete example:

```
class rand_var;
    rand bit abc;
    rand bit [3:0] cde;
    rand bit en;
endclass

module tb;

task custom_task();
    rand_var rand1;
    rand1 = new();
    if (!rand1.randomize(abc)) $display("randomization failed");
    $display("%b %d %b", rand1.abc, rand1.cde, rand1.en);
endtask

initial repeat (10) custom_task();

endmodule
```

Output:

```
1  0 0
1  0 0
1  0 0
0  0 0
1  0 0
1  0 0
0  0 0
1  0 0
1  0 0
0  0 0
```

Only `abc` is random for each task call.

---

See also [How to randomize only 1 variable in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66841562/how-to-randomize-only-1-variable-in-a-class)